# install Wordpress in the root directory

Tags: php, wordpress, debian

I'm trying to install wordpress on my debian server (Jessy),
I followed this tutorial:
https://wiki.debian.org/WordPress

I want to install it on the root directory (domain.com) but it don't work wordpress is only available on domain.com/wp

I think I should modify this part but I didn't find the way to do as I wish

```
  Alias /wp/wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
    Alias /wp /usr/share/wordpress
    <Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Could you help me on this please?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting the actual install of Wordpress, like the admin panel to be located at www.domain.com, or are you wanting the homepage of your Wordpress site to show up at www.domain.com?

Comment: Both would be ideal !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, 
I added the followind htaccess rule and it is now working:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp[L]
```